# Extending a class in java using inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

I had extended a class called Account from a class Interest

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Interest extends Account{
    public static void main(String args[]){

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int id =  scan.nextInt();
        double balance = scan.nextDouble();
        double rate = scan.nextDouble();
        int noOfYears = scan.nextInt();

        Account acc = new Account(id,balance,rate);
        double interest = calculateInterest(acc,noOfYears);
        System.out.println(interest);
        //System.out.println("%.3f",calculateInterest(acc,noOfYears));

     }

     public static double calculateInterest(Account acc, int noOfYears){
         return( acc.rate);
     }

  }

 class Account{
    int id;
    double balance;
    double rate;

    public Account(int id, double balance, double rate){
       this.id = id;
       this.balance = balance;
       this.rate = rate;
    }

    public int getId(){return id;}
    public double getBalance(){return balance;}
    public double getInterestRate(){return rate;}

}
```

I got an error as

> ```
> Interest.java:4: error: constructor Account in class Account cannot be applied to given types;
> class Interest extends Account{
> ^
>   required: int,double,double
>   found: no arguments
>   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
> 1 error
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because a subclass's constructor also needs to invoke its parent class's constructor. Since your class Account doesn't have a default constructor because you explicitly provide a constructor, compiler can't instantiate a default `super()` for you. You need to declare a constructor for Interest that looks like this

```java
public Interest(int id, double balance, double rate) {
    super(id, balance, rate);
    ...
    ...
}
```

And you might need to double check what you wanna do here. You aren't actually instantiating an Interest object at all in your code. It should be something like

```java
Account acc = new Interest(id,balance,rate);
```